# How to instantiate view and add it to Router using js in SAPUI5

Tags: view, sapui5, router

Is it possible to instantiate view and add it to Router using js in SAPUI5?

Something like:

```
var oView = sap.ui.core.view("<path>", "XML"); //instantiate xml view from string
oRouter.addRoute("routename", [<target-page-1", "target-page-2"], oView); //add the view to the router
```

Thanks!

Comment: The router certainly has the API [`addRoute`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router#methods/addRoute). Try it and let us know in the question, what worked and what didn't. Also, do you have the router settings in `manifest.json` or is the router created and controlled completely in JS?

Comment: I do have the Router settings in **manifest.json** but I am considering creating it and control it completely in js in case I don't find an alternative.